# Return certain keys from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array with this structure:

```
var resellerList = [
       {
        fId : 1,
        fName : 'Reseller 1 Name',
        fCityCode : 1,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       },
       {
        fId : 2,
        fName : 'Reseller 2 Name',
        fCityCode : 1,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       },
       {
        fId : 3,
        fName : 'Reseller 3 Name',
        fCityCode : 2,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       },
       {
        fId : 4,
        fName : 'Reseller 4 Name',
        fCityCode : 1,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       },
       {
        fId : 5,
        fName : 'Reseller 5 Name',
        fCityCode : 2,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       },
       {
        fId : 6,
        fName : 'Reseller 6 Name',
        fCityCode : 3,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       },
       {
        fId : 7,
        fName : 'Reseller 7 Name',
        fCityCode : 1,
        fTel : '+1234567890'
       }
];
```

Now I want select only objects with `fCityCode : 1` .

I know I should use `map` to found the index of value but `map` will return just index of one value.

```
var ePos = resellerList.map(function (x) {
            return x.fCityCode;
        }).indexOf(1);
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to select only items that match a certain condition from an array, the method to use is [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var cityCode1 = resellerList.filter(function (x) {
    return x.fCityCode === 1;
});
```

This will produce an array of objects where `fCityCode` is 1.

Comment: You should really have close-voted this as a duplicate.